# Can't get array from cmd line argument bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, count, ksh

For some reason in the code below for loop treats args as array and wc -l can count the lines correctly but I can't get the $(#args[@]) to produce the correct count

```
function doSomthing() {
local i args a
args=$1;
a=("1" "2" "3" "4");
i=0
  echo wc =`wc -l <<< "$args"`;
  for arg in $args; do
    ((i++))
    echo "$i"
  done;
  echo i = $i
  echo a = ${#a[@]}
  echo args = ${#args[@]}
  echo $args
}
```

The output of this function is

```
$> doSomthing $'1\n2\n3\n4'
wc =       4
1
2
3
4
i = 4
a = 4
args = 1
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args` is not an array; it is simply a string that contains embedded newlines. That means, if you try to treat it as an array, it will appear as if you defined it as

```
args=( $'1\n2\n3\4' )
```

not

```
args=(1 2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

I just needed to put $1 inside parenthesis.
For some reason when I tried it before it did not work but now it does. 

Here is the new code:

```
function doSomthing () {
    local i args a;
    args=( $1 );
    a=("1" "2" "3" "4");
    i=0;
    echo wc =`wc -l <<< "$args"`;
    for arg in $args; do
        ((i++));
        echo "$i";
    done;
    echo i = $i;
    echo a = ${#a[@]};
    echo args = ${#args[@]};
    echo ${args[@]}
}
```

And here is the new output:

```
$> doSomthing $'1\n2\n3\n4'
wc = 1
1
i = 1
a = 4
args = 4
1 2 3 4
```

Cheers ;-)

Comment: What do you expect as output if you run `doSomething "*"`? I rather suspect you might be surprised by what you get as output, if you run it from a non-empty directory.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.
I just did and got the same output as before (which is what I expected)

`ls -1`
1
2
3
4

`doSomthing "*"`
wc = 1
1
i = 1
a = 4
args = 4
1 2 3 4

I cannot show the output properly in a comment, but it is the same as before.

sorry.

Comment: If you want you can try viewing the following as html:


<br> `$> ls -1`
<br> 1
<br> 2
<br> 3
<br> 4

<br> `$> doSomthing "*"`
<br> wc = 1
<br> 1
<br> i = 1
<br> a = 4
<br> args = 4
<br> 1 2 3 4

Comment: Why do you expect that output to be `1 2 3 4`, instead of being `*`? It was **quoted**, after all: That's supposed to make it literal. Ifyou're expanding the glob, not treating it as a single argument when it was passed in a way that *makes* it a single argument, that's a bug.

Comment: So, let's say you had a file called `*** i am just one file *** .txt`. Silly name, with a bunch of spaces in it, but those exist sometimes. Right now, you couldn't make your code treat that filename as just one argument, no matter how you quote and escape it. That's my point: The way you're handling your arguments, right now, is **wrong**. In `doSomething "1 2 3 4" "5 6 7 8"`, you should have exactly *two* arguments, the first being `1 2 3 4`, and the second being `5 6 7 8`.

Comment: ...the conventional way to get an argument list into an array, then, is `array=( "$@" )`, which will precisely preserve the original list, with no limitations whatsoever on values (allowing values to contain literal newlines, allowing values to contain wildcards, etc).

Comment: Your problem is far from being solved. Now, actually, you have two problems: unlearn the wrong thing you learned and learn how to do things properly.

Comment: I am not sure what you want
I know that "1 2 3 4" and "5 6 7 8" will get to the function as 2 arguments.
My question was how to convert these single argument into an array.
I already solved the problem and posted the solution. I am also aware of the conventional way of doing that using "$@" but the was not good for me so I seeked another way. The code I posted in the question is not actually what I am trying to do but just a simple code to explain the but I needed for the question.